# Simple list in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple list in ASP.NET, I made one yesterday for one controller but now today I cannot get it to work in a new controller nor can I figure out why. Here's the controller from yesterday:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SubjectAccessRequests.Models;

namespace SubjectAccessRequests.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Person
        public ActionResult Person()
        {

            Person human = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Jack",
            LastName = "O'Neill",
            Age = 23,
        };

        Person adult = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            Age = 27,
        };

        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(human);
        people.Add(adult);

        return View(people);
    }
}
```

This works like a charm. Here's the views for the above controller:

```
@model IEnumerable<SubjectAccessRequests.Models.Person>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView");
    }

<h2>Person</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Now here's the controller from today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SubjectAccessRequests.Models;

namespace SubjectAccessRequests.Controllers
{
    public class AttemptController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Attempt
    public ActionResult Attempt()
    {
        Attempt story = new Attempt()
        {
            BookTitle = "Seabiscuit",
            Author = "Laura Hillenbrand",
        };

        Attempt play = new Attempt()
        {
            BookTitle = "King Lear",
            Author = "Shakespear",
        };

        return View(books);
    }

    //List<Attempt> books = new List<Attempt>();

    //books.Add(story);
    //books.Add(play);

    //return View(books);

}
}
```

And here's the views for the above controller:

```
    model IEnumerable<SubjectAccessRequests.Models.Attempt>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView");
}

<h2>Books</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

The commented section does not work. I have looked through all the code above and I have looked through all the related files for both controllers to see if I can spot any problem but I cannot for the life of me figure out why the list works in the first controller and not in the second - any help at all would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Added in the views for the two controllers!

Comment: "This does not work" is not helpful, please edit your answer and tell us exactly what is the problem. Including the code of the views for the corresponding controller actions might help as well :-)

Comment: The code has compilation error!

Comment: You have used a variable before its declaration!

Comment: JUst noticed that you have some code outside the `Attempt()` method

Comment: Ah thank you both, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your out of scope and returning books twice. Try -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SubjectAccessRequests.Models;

namespace SubjectAccessRequests.Controllers
{
    public class AttemptController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Attempt
    public ActionResult Attempt()
    {
        Attempt story = new Attempt()
        {
            BookTitle = "Seabiscuit",
            Author = "Laura Hillenbrand",
        };

        Attempt play = new Attempt()
        {
            BookTitle = "King Lear",
            Author = "Shakespear",
        };

       List<Attempt> books = new List<Attempt>();

      books.Add(story);
      books.Add(play);

      return View(books);
    }


}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I've been looking at it for so long I completely missed that I was trying to return it twice - it's one of those days..!

Comment: No problem, we all have those days!